# A Dedicated audio recording device with 3.5mm input and under $30?

Tags: audio, microphones, audio-recording

I'm looking for a dedicated audio recording device. I'm looking for something under $30 (or a bit more), and which:

- Has a 3.5mm connector mic socket, which also works with line-level audio.
- Has good audio quality, which means no noises from the device itself, at least 44.1kHz and stereo recording to WAV or some other lossless format.
- Has adjustable audio level, as well as displaying the audio level. Bonus points if you can hear what you're recording through the headphones.
- Bonus points if it takes SD or MicroSD cards instead of having built in storage, both to keep the cost down and because then I can swap out the card when it is full.
- I don't really care about the quality of the microphone, as I have my own high quality one. Would be even better if it has *no* built in mic - again, saves on price, and I would not use it much anyway.

I've looked around a bit, and devices with good quality start at around $60, so if I could get something like that, just without the built in mic and storage, that would work well for me.

Essentially, I'm looking for something like [this Zoom digital recorder](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Zoom-Portable-Digital-Recorder-Version/dp/B003QKBVYK/ref=sr_1_1), but without the built in microphone and a bit cheaper.

Does something like this exist? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There's a vibrant market for these "digital audio recorders" (also often called "digital voice recorders").  Here's a [Best Reviews description](https://www.amazon.com/ospublishing/story/6471bde0-69ff-41ce-920c-7fc31359381d/) of the current market.

E.g., the [EVISTR L36](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L8CLVY7) appears to check all your boxes.

(Note that the marginal cost of the mics can be negligible, so you probably won't find a DVR without one.)